# What is the magnitude of this transfer function?

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics

How can I calculate the magnitude of $G(s)$ ?

> $$G(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_n s+\omega_n^2}$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends on the variables that are in the function

Comment: @JanEerland let's say wn=2*pi and the damping is 0.07

Comment: @JanEerland so we have G(s)= (2pi)^2/(s^2+2*0.07*2pi*s+(2pi)^2)

Comment: Seems like some elementary complex number arithmetic to me...

Comment: @Ian how to solve it? I forgot everything about complex number.

Comment: Rewrite it in the usual real-imaginary part form by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator. Then use the usual "Pythagorean theorem" formula for the modulus.

Comment: as a semi-experienced user, you should know that a) you should give some context and b) write down your own effort/thoughts. Since you have done none of that -> close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for a complex function $G(s)$, its magnitude can be computed via $|G(s)| = \sqrt{G(s)G^*(s)}$, where $G^*(s)$ denotes complex conjugation.

In your case, $G(s)$ is rational and you can use the fact that $\left|\frac ab\right| = \frac{|a|}{|b|}$, i.e., form magnitude of enumerator and denominator separately.

Moreover, in these types of questions one is often interested in the magnitude of G(s) in the imaginary line, i.e., for $s=\jmath \omega$. This significantly simplifies things. The denominator is then  $(\jmath \omega)^2 + 2\jmath\zeta\omega_n\omega+\omega_n^2 = \omega_n^2-\omega^2 + 2\jmath\zeta\omega_n\omega$. This is already in the form $z = \Re\{z\}+\jmath \Im\{z\}$, which allows you to use the rule $|z| = \sqrt{\Re\{z\}^2+\Im\{z\}^2}$.

Connecting the dots, we then get
$$|G(\jmath \omega)| = \frac{\omega_n^2}{\sqrt{(\omega_n^2-\omega^2)^2 + 4\zeta^2\omega_n^2\omega^2}} $$.

In case you were looking for $|G(s)|$ outside the imaginary line I guess you can extend what I wrote easily by yourself.